# I'm getting an error while adding a new column with set up bins --TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm adding a new column to a dataframe it includes bins and labels.

It won't accept the column:

```
# set up bins
bins = [0, 585, 615, 645, 675]
group_name = ['0 - 584', '585 - 614', '615 - 644', '645 +']

# add a new column: spending range
score_by_school_spending["Spending Range"] = pd.cut(score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"],bins,labels=group_name)
score_by_school_spending
```

#### the error i received is as followed

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-7e730a291b70> in <module>
      1 # add a new column: spending range
----> 2 score_by_school_spending["Spending Range"]= pd.cut(score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"],bins,labels=group_name)
      3 score_by_school_spending

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest, duplicates)
    239                               include_lowest=include_lowest,
    240                               dtype=dtype,
--> 241                               duplicates=duplicates)
    242 
    243     return _postprocess_for_cut(fac, bins, retbins, x_is_series,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right, labels, precision, include_lowest, dtype, duplicates)
    342 
    343     side = 'left' if right else 'right'
--> 344     ids = ensure_int64(bins.searchsorted(x, side=side))
    345 
    346     if include_lowest:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

everywhere else it works but here its a wall

Comment: What is the dtype of `score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"]`?

Comment: score_by_school_spending ["Per Student Budget"] is str

Answer (score 0):

With the following data setup:

```
import numpy as np

score_by_school_spending= pd.DataFrame({"Per Student Budget": np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)})
```

your code outupts:

```
     Per Student Budget Spending Range
0                   378        0 - 584
1                   429        0 - 584
2                   428        0 - 584
3                   804            NaN
4                   967            NaN
..                  ...            ...
995                 435        0 - 584
996                  26        0 - 584
997                 104        0 - 584
998                  97        0 - 584
999                 452        0 - 584

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Please try your code again with:

```
score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"]= score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"].astype('float64')
```

Or better, check the output of

```
score_by_school_spending.dtypes
```

I guess the column is not numeric, because if on my data I perform:

```
score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"]= score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"].astype('str')
```

and rerun your code, I get (sounds familiar, doesn't it?):

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Because you mentioned, your strings contain dollar signs at the beginning, you can try

```
score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"]= score_by_school_spending["Per Student Budget"].str.replace('$', '')
```

in order to clean it.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$628.0'

Comment: I guess you need to convert the values properly. Remove the dollar signs. I added a line in my answer.

Comment: jottbe Thank you